# my first tsql proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my first tsql proc.

I have to group the information from a table into other table.  In my input table there may be more than one record for one person (`name` + `zip` + `dob` + `incident_date`)

I have to group them and add them to other table

```
Select  Distinct
        1                               As recordid,
        r.firstname + ' ' + r.lastname  As fullname,
        STUFF
        (
            (
                Select  ',' + Cast(a.[TicketID] As Varchar)
                From    tmp a
                Where   r.[FirstName] = a.[FirstName]
                And     r.[LastName] = a.[LastName]
                And     r.zip = a.zip
                And     r.dob = a.dob 
                And     r.incidentDate = a.incidentDate
                For XML Path('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
        )   As textCol2,
        (
            Select  Count(*)    cnt 
            From    tmp a 
            Where   r.[FirstName] = a.[FirstName]  
            And     r.[LastName] = a.[LastName] 
            And     r.zip = a.zip 
            And     r.dob = a.dob 
            And     r.incidentDate = a.incidentDate
        )   count_incident
From    tmp r
```

Is above sql is good  in performance

or
can you suggest me how to achieve this in store-procedure 
shall I open a loop and use variables to concatenate the records

```
create cursor c1 
select distinct [FirstName], [LastName],
                a.zip, dob, incidentDate from tmp
open cursor c1
while 
   code to fetch records for each row in c1
   open another cursor....
```

Comment: We can't give you much of an answer because you didn't us many details. You absolutely do NOT need to use cursors here.

Comment: sorry I was not clear. My question is do I really need procedure if I can do it in single sql. insert into target table select <above select statement> . Is this a better approach. Or  above code is bad code?

Comment: Thanks  Sean Lange. can you please suggest me how to  get the alternative of above sql in SP (stored procedure)

Comment: Well procedures are not required. I would suggest you do everything in procedures. That lets you create an application that is loosely coupled to the data. That means you change the query logic and not have to redeploy the application. It is the first step in creating application layers.

Comment: If you want to know how to make a procedure try this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sean Lange.  I am afraid if this sql is scale-able. My table will have millions of records.

Comment: Not sure how having millions of rows has anything to do with the decision of making this a procedure or not. A stored procedure is not inherently faster than an ad hoc query. But with millions of rows you absolutely need to avoid a cursor based approach like the plague. without more details like the table structure and index definitions any attempt at performance is a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Sean Lange has answered it. Thanks Sir

A stored procedure is not inherently faster than an ad hoc query. But with millions of rows you absolutely need to avoid a cursor based approach ...

Comment: You should write what he said inside the answer.  As it stands, this isn't really an answer.  But you should probably also let him write the answer so that he gets credit for it.